# DexExpress XPF Map in Windows Service

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary, devexpress

I'm using the DexExpress.Xpf.Map.v15.1 MapControl and trying to create code that will be able to run in a Windows Service (i.e. no front end) to generate maps as images.

I have the following code which creates a map, adds GeoPoints to a PolyLine and then adds that PolyLine to a map. This works fine in my WPF test harness application:

```
 public MapWindow1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            var mapControl = new MapControl
            {
                Name = "TheMap",
                ZoomLevel = 4,
                CenterPoint = new GeoPoint(47, 5)
            };

            var imageLayer = new ImageTilesLayer
            {
                DataProvider = new OpenStreetMapDataProvider()
            };
            mapControl.Layers.Add(imageLayer);

            var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer();
            mapControl.Layers.Add(vectorLayer);
            var mapItemStorage = new MapItemStorage();
            vectorLayer.Data = mapItemStorage;

            var polyLineCollection = DbfGenerator.GeneratePolyLineCollection();

            polyLineCollection.ForEach(line =>
            {
                var mapItem = new MapPolyline();
                mapItemStorage.Items.Add(mapItem);
                mapItem.Points.AddRange(line);
            });
            mapControl.MouseDoubleClick += mapControl_MouseDoubleClick;

            MainGrid.Children.Add(mapControl);

        }
```

This runs and adds the map control to the WPF page without a problem. I've then added double click handler to export the map as an image:

```
void mapControl_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            var m = GenerateMapPng((MapControl) sender);
            m.Save(@"C:\0Temp\test.bmp");
        }

 public Bitmap GenerateMapPng(MapControl map)
    {
        Bitmap bmp;
        // export image from map
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var exportOptions = new ImageExportOptions(ImageFormat.Png);
            map.ExportToImage(ms, exportOptions);


            ms.Position = 0;
            bmp = new Bitmap(System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms));
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

Again - this works without a problem. 
However, If I remove the UI element and run the following code:

```
public MapWindow1()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    var mapControl = new MapControl
    {
        Name = "TheMap",
        ZoomLevel = 4,
        CenterPoint = new GeoPoint(47, 5)
    };


    var imageLayer = new ImageTilesLayer
    {
        DataProvider = new OpenStreetMapDataProvider()
    };
    mapControl.Layers.Add(imageLayer);

    var vectorLayer = new VectorLayer();
    mapControl.Layers.Add(vectorLayer);
    var mapItemStorage = new MapItemStorage();
    vectorLayer.Data = mapItemStorage;

    var polyLineCollection = DbfGenerator.GeneratePolyLineCollection();

    polyLineCollection.ForEach(line =>
    {
        var mapItem = new MapPolyline();
        mapItemStorage.Items.Add(mapItem);
        mapItem.Points.AddRange(line);
    });

    var m = GenerateMapPng(mapControl);
    m.Save(@"C:\0Temp\test.bmp");

}
```

I get a NullReferenceException on the "`map.ExportToImage(ms, exportOptions);`" line.

I'm assuming that when the WPF application loads it calls a method to initialise the map, but I can't find anything that I can manually do to the control (Load/Init method) to mimic this.

Is there a way to trick the MapControl in to thinking it is in a WPF page when it isn't?

Comment: How would `var m = GenerateMapPng((MapControl) sender);` in the last code snippet ever compile when there is no `sender` variable anywhere?

Comment: Sorry @clemens - that was a copy and paste error. Now fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress said that this was not possible due to the maps reliance on the UI Thread in WPF